# How to retrieve data from firestore based on selection from spinner then calculate total cost to be displayed in textView

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

Anyone can help please with below my code ,Basically I want to fetch all data from firestore based on UserID and date range for specific month (ex: April) and get total cost for each row which will display in textView (id=spent)

my class as below:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_expense);


    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    userId = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    spent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spent);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(expense_view.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.month));
    myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);
    }
 final AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 =
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
//                 String s1 = String.valueOf(position);
////                    textView1.setText(s1);
                    System.out.println("positionss" + spinner2.getSelectedItem());
                if (spinner2.getSelectedItem().equals("April")) {
                    fStore.collection("data").whereEqualTo("ID", userId).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date", "01/4/2022").whereLessThanOrEqualTo("date", "31/4/2022").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                System.out.println("TEST"+task.getResult());
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                    String itemCost = document.getString("cost");

                                    String selected = itemCost.get(position).toString();
                                    Log.e("Clicked:",""+selected);


                                    total[0] += Integer.parseInt(itemCost);
                                    System.out.println("here2"+String.valueOf(total[0]));
                                    spent.setText("$" + total[0]);
                                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                            }
                        }

                    });

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }

        };
```

I have attached below images which demonstrate my data from firestore

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: hi @AlexMamo ,yes it does work but it need to be tweak as when i select from spinner value doesnt update value in spent textview based on date range given fStore.collection("data").whereEqualTo("ID", userId).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("date", "01/4/2022").whereLessThanOrEqualTo("date", "31/4/2022").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {